# how to get Bash script

Tags: bash

Need this script modified to give me the resulting filename, for example:

```
curl -s -H "User-Agent: cli:bash:v1.0.0 " \
https://www.reddit.com/r/aww/new/.json?limit=1 \
| jq '.data.children[].data.url' \
| xargs -P 0 -n 1 -I {} bash -c 'curl -s -O {}'

(your code here)
echo $theFileName
```

The filename should be taken from the command itself, not the drive. how can I make it?

Comment: Do not **ever** put `{}` inside the string passed to `bash -c '...{}...'` -- if you do so, a filename with `$(rm -rf ~)` in it will be executed as code (`$(rm -rf ~)'$(rm -rf ~)'` is also legal as a substring of a POSIX filename, so you can't just add single-quotes and expect that to protect you either). The safe practice is `xargs bash -c 'for arg; do curl -s -O "$arg"; done' _`

Comment: See [UsingFind#ActionsInBulk](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind#Actions_in_bulk:_xargs.2C_-print0_and_-exec_.2B-) for more discussion of safety around `xargs` use.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

EDITED: (thanks to @Chares Duffy)

```bash
while read url;do 
  theFileName=$(basename "$url")
  curl -s -O "$url"
done < <(curl -s -H "User-Agent: cli:bash:v1.0.0 " https://www.reddit.com/r/aww/new/.json?limit=1 | jq -r '.data.children[].data.url')

echo "$theFileName"
```

Comment: You mean `-O "$url"`, `echo "$theFileName"`, and `theFileName=$(basename "$url")`, right? (See [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo) and [SC2086](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2086))

Comment: Also, it'd be better to add the `-r` argument to `jq` so you don't need to strip any literal `"`s.